# Put-Call relationship for Option on Forward

Tags: option-pricing

The forward price of a forward contract maturing at time T on an asset with price St at time t is,

$$
F=S_te^{(r-q)(T-t)}
$$

where $r$ is the risk free rate and $q$ is the continuous dividend rate for $S_t$.

The Black Scholes equation for an option contingent on F is, 
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2F^2\frac{\partial ^2V}{\partial F^2} -rV = 0
$$

How do i show that the prices of European call, C, and put options, P, on the forward F, with the same strike K and expiry date $T_1$, where $T_1 < T$ (ie, the options expire before the forward matures), are related by

$$
C(F,t)=\frac{F}{K}P(\frac{K^2}{F},t)
$$

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to define the call and put option payoffs to recognize their relationship.

Comment: this is a model-dependent result. What modelling assumptions are you willing to make?

Comment: i have updated the post with more information. Just wanted to figure out how do we usually go about thinking of these problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{F(t, T), 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ be the forward process that satisfies an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dF(t, T) = \sigma F(t, T) dW_t,
\end{align*}
where $\sigma$ is the constant volatility, $\{W_t, t>0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. The payoff at time $T_1$, where $0 < T_1 \leq T$, of a vanilla European forward option is of the form
\begin{align*}
\max(\psi (F(T_1, T)-K), \, 0),
\end{align*}
where $\psi = 1$, for a call option, and $-1$, for a put option. Note that, for any $0\leq t \leq T_1$,
\begin{align*}
F(T_1, T) = F(t, T) \exp\Big(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t) + \sigma \sqrt{T_1 -t} \xi \Big),
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ is a standard normal random variable. Then the value at time $t$ of the option payoff above is given by
\begin{align*}
d(t, T_1)\psi\Big[F(t, T) \Phi\big(\psi d_1(F)\big) -K \Phi\big(\psi d_2(F)\big) \Big],
\end{align*}
where $d(t, T_1)$ is the discount factor, 
\begin{align*}
d_1 (F) = \frac{\ln \frac{F(t, T)}{K} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_2 (F) = \frac{\ln \frac{F(t, T)}{K} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
C(F, t) = d(t, T_1)\Big[F(t, T) \Phi\big(d_1(F)\big) -K \Phi\big(d_2(F)\big) \Big],
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
P(F, t) = d(t, T_1)\Big[K \Phi\big(-d_2(F)\big) -F(t, T) \Phi\big(-d_1(F)\big)\Big],
\end{align*}
Note that, by replacing $F$ in $d_1$ with $K^2/F(t, T)$,
\begin{align*}
d_1 \Big(\frac{K^2}{F}\Big) &= \frac{\ln \frac{K^2/F(t, T)}{K} +\frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma}\\
&= \frac{-\ln \frac{F(t, T)}{K} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma}\\
&= -d_2(F).
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
d_2 \Big(\frac{K^2}{F}\Big) &= \frac{\ln \frac{K^2/F(t, T)}{K} -\frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma}\\
&= \frac{-\ln \frac{F(t, T)}{K} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} (T_1 -t)}{\sqrt{T_1-t}\,\sigma}\\
&= -d_1(F).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{F}{K}P\bigg(\frac{K^2}{F}, t \bigg) &= d(t, T_1)\frac{F}{K}\Bigg[K \Phi\bigg(-d_2\bigg(\frac{K^2}{F}\bigg)\bigg) -\frac{K^2}{F} \Phi\bigg(-d_1\bigg(\frac{K^2}{F}\bigg)\bigg)\Bigg]\\
&= d(t, T_1)\bigg[F \Phi\Bigg(-d_2\bigg(\frac{K^2}{F}\bigg)\bigg) -K \Phi\bigg(-d_1\bigg(\frac{K^2}{F}\bigg)\bigg)\Bigg]\\
&= d(t, T_1)\Big[F(t, T) \Phi\big(d_1(F)\big) -K \Phi\big(d_2(F)\big) \Big]\\
&= C(F, t).
\end{align*}

Comment: Changed the discount factor from $d(t, T)$ to $d(t, T_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think one way about it is maybe like below...

Consider value of a call option on the forward at time $t$ and forward price $F$, and the value of a put at time $t$ and forward price $(K^2/F)$. Assume they have the same strike price $K$.

Then at time $T_1$ ( option expiry ), we have
$$
C( F,T_1 ) = ( F - K )^+ \\
P( \frac{K^2}{F}, T_1 ) = (K-\frac{K^2}{F})^+
$$

Dividing C by P,

$$
\frac{C( F,T_1 )}{P( \frac{K^2}{F}, T_1 ) }=\frac{ ( F - K )^+}{(K-\frac{K^2}{F})^+}=\frac{ (F - K )^+}{K(\frac{F-K}{F})}=\frac{F}{K}
$$

The condition should hold for all previous times $t<T_1$. Therefore,

$$
C( F,t)=\frac{F}{K}P( \frac{K^2}{F}, t )
$$