# forward option, stochastic calculus

Tags: stochastic-calculus, forward, stochastic

I encounter a problem to understand this:

The price of a forward option is :
$C(K,t,T)=\mathbb{E}[((S_{T}/S_{t})-K)+]$ **OK**

The option should only depend on $T-t$ because the yield randomness (for a week) in 2 years should be the same as the yield randomness (for a week) in 3 years and that will be the same as the yield randomness (for a week) today if no known events are expected **WHY ?**

Then taking $X_{t}=ln(S_{t}/S_{0})$ we should have:
for all $u$ and for all $a$, $X_{u+a}-X_{u}=X_{a}$ (equality in distribution) **WHY ?**

Thank you

Comment: This appears a forward start option. For a forward option, you may refer to  http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17153/put-call-relationship-for-option-on-forward/17257#17257.

Comment: I don't understand why the link you provided would help me... I search on google "forward start option" but i found nothing that would help me to understand the last 2 sentences of my first post.
For the first one: is it related to the Black-Scholes model ?
For the second one; how do we conclude with the stationary increments ???
Thank you

Comment: below may answered partial of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last question. We assume that 
\begin{align*}
S_t = S_0 e^{(r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t},
\end{align*}
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion, $r$ is the interest rate, $q$ is the dividend yield, and $\sigma$ is the volatility.
Then,
\begin{align*}
X_{u+a}-X_a &= (r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)a + \sigma(W_{u+a}-W_u)\\
&\sim (r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)a + \sigma W_a\\
&= X_a.
\end{align*}

For the forward start option, note that
\begin{align*}
S_T/S_t &= e^{(r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t) + \sigma (W_T- W_t)}\\
&= e^{(r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t) + \sigma \sqrt{T-t}\xi},
\end{align*}
where $\xi$ is a standard normal random variable. Then
\begin{align*}
C(K, t, T) &= e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}\big(S_T/S_t -K)^+ \big)\\
&= e^{-rT}\big[N(d_1) - KN(d_2) \big],
\end{align*}
where  $N$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, 
\begin{align*}
d_{1} = \frac{\ln (1/K) + (r-q+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 )(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_{2} = \frac{\ln (1/K) + (r-q- \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 )(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}